# Could not parse authorization token when exporting as a bearer token in postman

Tags: postman, bearer-token

I am trying to pass the authorization token as a bearer token in my next postman request but that is showing the error :

"message": "Could not parse authorization token."

This is what I have written in the first post request where the token gets generated:

```
var jsonData= pm.response.json;
var token = jsonData.token;
pm.globals.set("token", token);
```

This is my response body:

```
{
    "expiresIn": 8**00,
    "token": "foo....bar"
}
```

The token successfully gets generated and then I want to use that as a bearer token in my next GET request. This is what I have put in the header of the second request as key value format:

Authorization : Bearer {{token}}
[image]

This is the error I get from the get request:

```
"message": "Could not parse authorization token."
```

If I use the actual token like Authorization :Bearer foo...bar then it works but using {{token}} does not. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the bearer token is set after your first request? You could verfiy that by hovering over the variable `{{token}}`.

Comment: On hover the token appears empty. So the error is in the set method. How do I fix it?

Comment: What's the response body? Is `accessToken` the correct property name? Is it nested in a different object?

Comment: As @DannyDainton pointed out, it would be easier for us to analyze your issue if you would supply your response body that contains the `accessToken`.

Comment: I have added the response body. The property name is "token" and it is not nested
@DannyDainton

Comment: Have you tried just using the Authorization tab in Postman and selecting Bearer Token as the Type then putting in your token?

Comment: yes, I get the same error using authorization tab